# Using a value from one worksheet, check for values on another worksheet and return to a cell

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have two workbooks. Let's call them "Main" and "Aux".

I'm writing a function that will run on "Main" and will use data from "Aux".

"Main" has a list of people on one worksheet. For each person, I want to check on workbook "Aux" which skills that person has with grade >=3, to concatenate them and fill a cell on workbook "Main".

This is the code I've wrote so far. The problem is the range is referring to the "Main" workbook, and the data I want is on "Aux" workbook.

A skill is identified when Column "A" has "Technical"

- Column G on "Aux" book holds the name for each person.
- Column D on "Aux" holds the name of the skill
- Variables deb and deb2 are used for debugging using MsgBox

Code:

```
Public Function Arroz(name As String) As String

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strID As String
    Dim strDay As String
    Dim skillsAs String
    Dim deb As String
    Dim deb2 As String


    strID = "Person number one"
    strDay = "Technical"
    skills= ""


    Set rngFound = Workbooks("Aux.xlsx").Sheets("Skills Mao").Columns("G").Find(strID, Cells(Rows.Count, "G"), xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Do
            deb = Cells(rngFound.Row, "A").Text
            deb2 = Cells(rngFound.Row, "M").Value
            MsgBox deb
            MsgBox deb2
            If LCase(Cells(rngFound.Row, "A").Text) = LCase(strDay) And Cells(rngFound.Row, "M").Value >= 4 Then
               skills = skills & Cells(rngFound.Row, "D").Text & " ,"
            End If
            Set rngFound = Columns("G").Find(strID, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
    End If
    strLast = rngFound.Address
    Set rngFound = Nothing

    Arroz = competencies
    Exit Function
    End Function
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when you run this code?  Do you get an error message?  Does `rngFound` return nothing when it should have found something?

Comment: When I run this code, I get a value from worksheet "Main" when I was expecting from worshkeet "Aux"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the use of `Cells` without specifying a sheet.  When you do that `Cells` will refer to the active sheet i.e. "Main" as you have named it.  Try something like this:

```
' ------ More of your existing code above ------
strID = "Person number one"
strDay = "Technical"
skills= ""

' ----- My added snippit -----
Dim shAux as Worksheet
Set shAux = Workbooks("Aux.xlsx").Sheets("Skills Mao")
Set rngFound = shAux.Columns("G").Find(strID, shAux.Cells(Rows.Count, "G"), xlValues, xlWhole)
```

Then use `shAux.Cells` wherever you want cells from that sheet in place of `Cells` alone.